# Plotting points in 3D space

Tags: opencl

I'm looking to plot the points in a 3D space. I find that languages like python with matplotlib, take a lot of time. What would be the simple way to do it in opencl ?

Comment: are you sure you don't mean OpenGL? (where you can use `glBegin(GL_POINTS) ...`)

Comment: You need gl_interop in opencl to preapare your geometries then use that in opengl. opencl is computing language and opengl is graphics language.